# Meaning of 'yet' in certain sentence

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me if it means that interview stage is already ended or has not started yet (it will start in the near future)

> Please be advised, "company name" are not looking to progress anyone else to the interview stage yet. If the circumstances change at any stage we will keep you informed and will let you know In due course in order for you to arrange accommodation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite this way:

> "company name" are not **yet** looking to progress anyone *else*

*not yet* means that the *looking* (movement to the interview stage) is presently stopped.

But also important here is the use of *else*, meaning that this stoppage only applies to future applicants. It is possible others were already interviewed before the time of the statement.